# Facebook Instant Articles in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, facebook-instant-articles

I want to install facebook instant article on my website in Drupal 7.

I installed the module and all the necessary elements (following this https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_instant_articles and this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/quickstart/ ) and tried to set it all but I can not get my articles on Facebook?

How work the API facebook instant article in Drupal ? Or where can I put watchog() to tried to identified my problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Vincent LEVEQUE

Answer (score 0):

The fb_instant_articles module has a setting on the admin page to include API responses in the dblog. This is the best way to get to the root of the issue.